# Rss Widget: Data is not displayable

Tags: android, rss

I'm using the [Simplistic-RSS][1] library from ShirwaM to display my Rss-link as widget. I don't why my project isn't working. The thing is that Asynctask works fine, but the result data won't be displayed on in ListView. All is working perfect if the listview gets filled with dummydata.

Please have a look at my project. I used Android Studio.
https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23991606952614831
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxU5LL-LGpOPTkk2RW1QeGFYME0/view?usp=sharing

## Some snippets:

**RemoteViewsService (`.widget.Service.class`):**

```
@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
            AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    return (new Provider(this.getApplicationContext(), intent));
}

class Provider(Context applicationContext, Intent intent) {
        context = applicationContext;
        appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
//        new GetRssFeed().execute(RSS_SOURCE_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        Log.i("getViewAt", String.valueOf(position));
        if (position == 0 || position == 1) {
            Log.i("getViewAt", " is working (" + position + ")");
        }
        final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
                context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.item_awidget);
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.title,"toto");
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.content1, "titi");
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.content2,"titit");
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.content3, "fhjfhjf");
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.content4, "EMPTY");
        return remoteView;
    }
//

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() { return null; }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //  new GetRssFeed().execute(RSS_SOURCE_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() { }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return feeds.size(); }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() { return 1; }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() { return true; }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        //   new GetRssFeed().execute(RSS_SOURCE_URL);
    }
```

**AsyncTask (`to bring in`):**

```
    public class GetRssFeed extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem>> {
        @Override
        protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(params[0]);
                Log.i("dpInBack ", String.valueOf(rssReader.getItems().size()));
                return rssReader.getItems();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("Error Parsing Data", e + "");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> pList ) {
            Log.i("list size ", String.valueOf(pList.size()));
            for(int i=0; i<pList.size(); i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    Log.i("onPostExecute", pList.get(i).getTitle());
                }
                RssItem item = new RssItem();
                item.setTitle(pList.get(i).getTitle());
                item.setDescription(pList.get(i).getDescription());
                item.setLink(pList.get(i).getLink());
                item.setImageUrl(pList.get(i).getImageUrl());
                feeds.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I you get some error please post it.

Comment: @omainegra Nope, sorry.. There's nothing to add.. If I fill the widgets ListView with LoremText it's working fine. If it gets filled with the output of the rssreader list, the data won't be displayed.

Comment: @omainegra I've found the error. AsyncTask isn't available in `RemoteViewsService`. [Check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30824866/4406921)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I finally found out how to fix it. The trick is to use the `RemoteViewsFactory` and **not** to use `AsyncTask`. It's not possible to use `AsyncTask` in this context.

**For example, change..**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    new GetRssFeed().execute(RSS_SOURCE_URL);
}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    new GetRssFeed().execute(RSS_SOURCE_URL);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() { }


public class GetRssFeed extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem>> {
        @Override
        protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(String... params) { [..] }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> pList ) { [..] }
    }
```

**To..**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    feeds.clear;
    initData();
}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    feeds.clear;
    initData();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    feeds.clear;
}

public initData(){ [..] }
```